# Verifying the presence of an option in a list?

Tags: ruby, automation, cucumber

I'm writing automated tests using Cucumber and SitePrism. One test adds a user role to a list, and I'm having trouble verifying the presence of the role (to verify it's successfully assigned) in the final steps.

The gherkin is...

```
Scenario: Assigning roles to a user
   Given I have reached the user edit view in the admin
   When I click the Assign Roles tab
     And select the first value in the Add Role dropdown
     And click Add role
   Then I should receive the message of save successful
     And the role should be present in the current role list
```

...With `And the role should be present in the current role list` being the step I'm having trouble with. After the `And click Add role` step executes, the HTML for the list appears as such...

```
<dd>
  <select id="current-role-a02322d1-8add-4234-aeca-02d3fca2a239" class="current-role" name="role_id" multiple="multiple">
    <option title="System Administrator Role" value="1">Administrator</option>
  </select>
</dd>
```

This one I'm stuck on. What do I set the element as on the page model, and what do I write in my step definitions to verify the presence of `<option title="System Administrator Role" value="1">Administrator</option>` and make the step fail if it's not present? I would prefer to be checking for `value="1"` instead of the `title` or text.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Why have you tagged `Capybara` when your question has cucumber's code in it?

Comment: The tag should be related to what's *directly* involved in the question. People care because properly curating the questions is what StackOverflow is all about.

Comment: I don't think this question has anything to do with Cucumber. You can use any library you choose in a step definition, and the question seems to be about writing a step definition that interacts with a web page.

Answer (score 1):

Define a method on your page model that will extract the value that you are trying to assert. This method will contain the element definition and then .text or .value at the end of your element definition. Here you can use value = "1" or title.

In your step definition, call the method and assert that the returned value is equal to "Administrator".